# why $||e_i||^2$ implies $\lambda_i\gt 0$ $\forall i$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

I have some questions on the following proof:

Let $S$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix. Then:

$S$ is p.d (positive definite) if and only if every eigenvalue of $S$ is strictly positive $(\gt0)$

Proof:

Suppose $S$ is p.d. Let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $S$. Let $e_1,...,e_n$ be the corresponding eigenvectors. Hence,

$$0\lt e^T_iSe_i=e^T_i\lambda_ie_i=\lambda_ie^T_ie_i=\lambda||e_i||^2$$

for every $i$ and since $||e_i||^2\gt 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lambda_i\gt0, \forall i.$

Conversely... (and the proof continues)

> What I don't understand is why $||e_i||^2$ implies $\lambda_i\gt 0$ $\forall i$?

Comment: You already have $0<\lambda_i \|e_i\|^{2}$. Isn't it obvious that $\lambda_i>0$?

Comment: For all $i$ the above inequality holds, since $e_i$ is an eigenvalue, in particular its norm cannot be $0$. This means that $||e_i||^2>0$. This forces $\lambda>0$, you can just divide by norm square on both side.

Comment: @JustWandering oh okay, it forces it because of the inequality above. Thanks, I didn't notice/realize that!